# FireFox 40: No Proxy(SOCKS5) Authorization Prompt

Tags: firefox, proxy, socks5

Mac OS X 10.10.5

Firefox 40.0.3

Does anyone know how to get FireFox to prompt for username/password when trying to set up a SOCKS5 proxy? I read that many people have issues with being asked to often to login but I can't get asked even once to login.

I have tried modifying the true/false value of:

```
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies
network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies
```

both there is no change.

I have tried scouring the internet for a solution but nothing seems to make a change in not being able to authenticate the login.

~ update ~

Here is a link to the proxy setup section that mentions configuring proxy for HTTP, SSL, FTP and maybe SOCKS5: http://oi60.tinypic.com/4tsrba.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox does not support SOCKS5 authentication](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122752). Neither do other browsers, at least as far as I am aware.

The settings you found refer to regular (HTTP) proxies.

If you really want to use a proxy that needs authentication, you need a wrapper, like [socksify](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/socksify.1.html) on Linux systems. I’m not aware of any non-defunct Windows software offering similar functionality. Sockscap used to be available, but its continued existence is nebulous at best.

Comment: Great, not allowed to post an image of where in FireFox settings they have a place for HTTP, SSL, FTP, and SOCKS proxy setup. But there is a spot.

Comment: I added a link to my original post with a link to a screenshot of FireFox's settings for proxies.

Comment: Oh you are saying that authentication isn't supported. That's.. frustrating I guess. It would be nice if it was easier to find out that certain aspects weren't supported, I thought everyone using FireFox was getting prompted too often on this issue when I couldn't get prompted at all. Thank you for your time and help on this.